# Success Message Persist On all pages

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, global-messages

we are saving the customer account information (like personal info, address etc) from the customer account section(frontend after login), it show the success message on same page. So this is right but after it persist on all page even if I reload the same page still it's come.

It come on all pages: cart pages, order history page, wishlist page etc.

we didn't make any customisation in customer module.

and we are using the same way to display the message in our template like magento do in default:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`

Answer (score 0):

When the messages are read from the session, they are deleted, this means either you are doing the displaying of the message custom way or you add the message all the time again.